# How to get addressibility to individual Angular components?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

**Environment:** Angular 7 using the ng-select component.

**Scenario:** A *ngFor which creates a list of ng-select components as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let address of addresses">
  <ng-select    
     [items]="address.cities"
     bindLabel="name"
     bindValue="id">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

The ng-select component has methods which I need to call. How do I get each instance of ngSelect instance in order to call those methods from the model side.

I am able to see the decomposed htmlelements in the DOM but I don't want to traverse the DOM I just want to call certain ng-select methods but don't know how to get an instance of the component from the model.

An example of a method call would be:

```
instanceOfNgSelect.HandleClear();
```

I would want access to any of the instances created from the *ngFor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
<div *ngFor="let address of addresses">
  <ng-select    
     [items]="address.cities"
     bindLabel="name"
     bindValue="id">
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

The best way to get addressibility to any of the ng-selects above is in the Model using the ViewChildren decorator:

```
@ViewChildren(NgSelectComponent) NgSelectComponents: QueryList<NgSelectComponent>;
```

Then in ngAfterViewInit():

```
  this.NgSelectComponents.forEach(ngselect=>{
     debugger;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly, you want to call second one out of 4? if so, did you try initiating index when looping? *ngFor="auth of authors, let i = index;", that case you can pass the index and identify based on the index.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try...and report back